# How can I install a printer driver to be shared across multiple printers with different connections

Tags: windows-7, usb, parallel-port

I have several printers (same model) with a parallel (printer) to USB cable.

The printers are in different locations, but the portable PC's (Panasonic CF-19) running Windows 7 will install a new printer/driver for each printer when a USB2USB cable is plugged into the PC.

I would like to have one printer defined and recognised by plugging in the parallel2USB cable.

With Windows XP, there was a Registry Key to remove and it all worked fine.  Windows 7 does not have that key.

How can I install a printer/driver for this printer that can be used with any of these different printers when they are all the same make and model?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that all your LPT2USB adapters are the same - you could tell Windows to ignore USB serial numbers for the adapters.

Under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\UsbFlags\` create REG_BINARY value named `IgnoreHWSerNum{Device VID, PID in hex}` and set it to `1`

So for a device with VID=0x1234 and PID=0x5678 it will be `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\UsbFlags\IgnoreHWSerNum12345678`

Unplug the adapter, remove all the extra printers, reboot the PC, reconnect the printer and reinstall the driver. From now on plugging in of the same model LPT2USB adapter should not prompt to install any more drivers.